# How to use regular expression matching groups in batch renames?

Tags: regex, powershell-2.0, file-rename, batch-rename

I'm trying to do some regular expression based bulk renames with PowerShell.

This succesfully gives me only the files I need:

```
Get-ChildItem . | Where-Object { $_.Name -cmatch "(\b|_)(L|H|M|X{1,3})(_|\b)" }
```

*(all those that contain an uppercase L, M, X, ...)*

Next, I want to rename, i.e. `mycustom_M.png` to `processed_M.png`, `another_L.png` to `processed_L.png`, and so forth.

Basically, I would use the regexp `.*?(?:\b|_)(L|H|M|X{1,3})(?:_|\b).*` to select the names, and `processed_\1.png` to replace them if I was in Notepad++, but I can't get it to work in PowerShell (I'm surely missing the right syntax here):

```
[...] | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace ".*?(?:\b|_)(L|H|M|X{1,3})(?:_|\b).*","banner_$Matches.groups[1].value" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backreferences in PowerShell start with a `$`, not a `\`. However, you must either put the replacement expression in single quotes or escape the `$`, otherwise PowerShell would expand the `$1` as a regular variable:

```
$pattern = ".*?(?:\b|_)(L|H|M|X{1,3})(?:_|\b).*"
... | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace $pattern, 'banner_$1' }
```

or

```
$pattern = ".*?(?:\b|_)(L|H|M|X{1,3})(?:_|\b).*"
... | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace $pattern, "banner_`$1" }
```

Comment: Ah, didn't think about escapes! Worked like a charm. Thanks.